# Charles Proxy blocking SSL traffic on Android

Tags: android, charles-proxy

Been using Charles Proxy for years now but recently I've been having issues setting up my Android device.

Certificates have been installed on the Android device. I've confirmed they are in fact listed as trusted certificates in my certificates list. Everything is setup correctly, but SSL traffic continues to be blocked.

I've tried reaching out for support, but they don't ever respond.

Has anybody had this issue before?

Comment: Do you have a network security config file in place? Please refer: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.  I am using Charles every day and I don't have any issues. Also, it won't work on release build because debuggable option will be false.

Comment: If you just want to track network traffic you can do that with the new network profiler introduced in Android Studio 3: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler

Answer (score 7):

I was having all my traffic blocked. The issue was that "Allow list" (in Tools menu) was enabled, so only traffic to allowed locations were going through. After disabling that, issue got fixed.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is setup correctly, but SSL traffic continues to be blocked.

Sometimes I used to see red cross on SSL requests coming from Android. I was unable to read the content. It started working fine for me after I setup the `SSP Proxy Settings` option. I checked the `Enable SSL Proxying` option as shown in the image and added the wildcard URL's that I want to filter. Eg: `*.your-server-url.com`

[image]

**Update:**

Also I don't think you can do it in release build of your application.

And for Android N and above there have been these changes you'll need to include in your project for it to work: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/

Hope this helps a bit.